# Are there any other non-differentiable that came be constructed from summation besides the Weierstrass function?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

So, I'd like to see conditions on a function $f(n,t)$ such that $F(t)$ from,

$$F(t)=\sum_n f(n,t)$$

Is continuous over a non-zero range, but is nowhere differentiable. The range of the summation could be anything, I don't really care.

**My Conjecture**

Such a function $f(n,t)$ only exists if it is periodic with respect to $t$.

I'd love to see a counter example :)

Comment: If $g(n,t)$ are the terms in any sequence that sum to the zero function, then you can add them to the $f$s and maintain the sum. Certainly, you can choose the $g$s to destroy any periodicity that might have been present in the original terms.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Theoretically, but then the sum has to be a function that's differentiable and bounded...I mean the problem becomes trivial otherwise.

Comment: If $\sum f(n,t)$ is nowhere differentiable, then so is $\sum e^tf(n,t).$

Comment: @zhw. Makes sense, to make a claim addressing that would weaken my conjecture considerably. Thanks!